# Close child tab, redirect parent tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two html pages **one.html** and **two.html**

**one.html** page contain below code

```
<a href="two.html" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

When i click on Google it will redirect to two.html page.

**two.html** page contain below code

```
<a href="">Go back</a>
```

*Now what i want is when user click on Go back, close two.html and redirect to parent window one.html page*

Answer (score 0):

First of all I am not able to understand why you want to do this, but if you really want, you can use below code -

**one.html**  -

```
<a href="two.html" target="_blank" onclick="window.close();">Google</a>
```

**two.html**  -

```
<a href="one.html" target="_blank" onclick="window.close();">Go back</a>
```

Please check and confirm

Answer (score 0):

You can add the below code under two.html:

```
<a href="" onclick = "javascript:self.close();">Go back</a>
```

I hope it works!!!!